# Iptables port redirection without packet loss

Tags: iptables

Let' say we have two instances of webserver listening on port 80 and 81 and I want to seamlessly redirect customer traffic without losing any  packets from instance1 to instance2.
My understanding that simple NEW match would work.Is it correct?

$ iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -j REDIRECT --to-port 81

I expect old connection to be open until they are closed and any new connections would be redirected to the new port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to also allow input on the port you're redirecting to.

```
--iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 81 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Thank you Peter, my assumption was that no other rules are in place